# Extract GET and POST parameters from client socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, http

I'm writing a server application in Java. Each time a user access the server via a browser, a new client socket is created. Is there a nice way to extract GET, POST and header information from that client socket? E.g. if a client acceses `localhost:PORT/somefile.html` , I would like to extract "somefile.html" information.

Comment: Do you want an HTTP parser?

Comment: Google for "servlet".

Comment: Yes, something like that. Anything that would help me extract the requested file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just writing a TCP/IP socket program, it doesn't understand the HTTP protocol until you program all that.  Either find a HTTP Server library, or just be realistic and install a servlet container like Tomcat and write JSP/Servlets. Writing a webserver is generally a waste of time since its a complex task and you can find several already made.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a very simple, yet completed http get/post parser in pure core java,
see: http://kuchaguangjie.iteye.com/blog/2002257

It's just a very simple example, the full version has concurrent support, but too large to put there.
Source code of `tomcat` or `netty` would be good reference to write a http parser. 
A book called "How Tomcat Works" would be a good guide too.

Comment: Looks like spam to me.

Comment: @developerwjk yeah, you can't understand it unless you have read http protocol specification.

Comment: No. There's nothing at that link but a bunch of Chinese characters and a login form.